# What is the meaning of the phrase "staring at starvation"?

Tags: usage, phrases

I read a sentence which was:

> A lack of dignified employment, non payment of adequate wages on time
>   and insufficient food mean that the family of four is in a dicey
>   situation and **staring at starvation**.

What is the meaning of **staring at starvation** in the sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Cambridge Dictionary

**[be staring at something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-staring-at-sth)**

> If you are staring at **a bad situation** or problem, you know you must
>   experience it or **deal with it very soon**:
>
> *By late in the first half the team was staring at almost certain
>   defeat.*

In the Oxford Dictionary, we found a related phrase

[**be staring something in the face**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stare)

> Be on the verge of defeat, death, or another unpleasant fate.

In your sentence the unpleasant fate / bad situation is **starvation**. That family is going to face starvation soon if their problems are not solved.